# PTY module not recognizing input to reader

Tags: ruby, io, pty

I have the following Ruby code to connect to a vpn using openconnect. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

```
require 'pty'
require 'expect'

PTY.spawn("sudo openconnect --juniper --user myusername --csd-wrapper tncc.py vpnserver") do |reader, writer|
  puts reader.expect(/sudo/, 3) # cont. in 3s if input doesn't match
  writer.puts('my sudo password')
  reader.expect(/password/, 5)
  write.puts('my vpn password')
  sleep 5
  puts "cmd response: #{reader.gets}" #returns 'for rich:'
end
```

I've tested that the expect matches what it should, but it appears that it never gets past the sudo prompt, based on the fact that it outputs 'for rich:' as in, `[sudo] password for rich:` I expect it to prompt me for a sudo password and then prompt me for a vpn password.

Comment: If I remember right, `sudo` forces input to come from the keyboard which breaks "expect"-like processing. I generally run the script using `sudo ruby path/to/script` so the sudo processing occurs prior to Ruby getting control.